# Out of memory (allocated 27262976) (tried to allocate 294912 bytes) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have written a Script in PHP which takes 2+ Hour to Execute Completely, Actually I am scrapping a Website completely.

I have used PHP Laravel 5.0 Framework to write that Script, even after  ini_set("memory_limit",-1), I am getting same Out Of Memory Error.

My RDP have 1 GB RAM, Is there ANY WAY TO PERMANENTLY FIX THIS? 
In my PHP.ini, I have also increased the limit still it says :(

Comment: Time != Memory anyway. Hard to guess how to optimize it without seeing the code, though.

Comment: @DamienPirsy , is there any setting need to be done in PHP that makes the code works for (WHATEVER) time and memory it takes till the end .. and don't return any error untill it ends completely ?

Comment: It sounds like you have a rather nasty *bug* in your program.

Comment: you have to optimize the memory.. unset the unwanted variables, unload unwanted files etc.. try to get the memory usage report and then take decisions based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset any arrays/objects you might use during your script running time. This is most probably the case, you're extracting a lot of data and once you compute whatever you need to compute, you don't "free" the memory